# How can I reduce steps in python regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

This is my regex

> **([^>]+?[<])/?(?!a)(?:br|p)**

This is example

`<r> this is text which I do not want <a> This is what I want!<br>`

I just want to scrap text between '>' and '< br or p'

This regex works exactly I want, but I realize that it takes time too much.

I ran this on regex debugger it took over 800 step to check wrong sentence.

how can I fix it?

Comment: I believe you need `>([^<]+)<(?:br|p)\b` and use it with `re.findall`. See https://ideone.com/z9hVQ4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `([^>]+?[<])/?(?!a)(?:br|p)` pattern means:

- `([^>]+?[<])` - Capture into Group 1 one or more (but as few as possible) chars other than `>` up to the first `<`
- `/?` - match an optional `/` symbol
- `(?!a)(?:br|p)` - match either `br` or `p` that do not start with `a` (so, the lookahead makes no sense).

Basically, it only returns text before `</br>`, `<br` or `<p`. You can just use

```
>([^<]+)</?(?:br|p)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG7mH0/1) (21 steps on your valid match, and 9 steps against the non-matching string `<r> this is text which I do not want <a> This is what I want!br>`).

**Pattern details**:

- `>` - a literal `>`
- `([^<]+)` - Capture group 1 matching one or more characters other than `<`
- `<` - a literal `<`
- `/?` - an optional (one or zero) `/`
- `(?:br|p)\b` - either `br` or `p` that are followed with a word boundary (there must be a non-word char after these values).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/z9hVQ4):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'>([^<]+)</?(?:br|p)\b')
s = "<r> this is text which I do not want <a> This is what I want!<br>"
print(p.findall(s))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this answer is just exactly what I have wanted!

Answer (score 0):

This is fewer steps:

`>([^<]+)<(?:br|p)`

https://regex101.com/r/hS2dI4/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to scrap text between '>' and '< br or p' not <a> and <br> . That text is just one of simple example.

Comment: Then make a complex example. Make five examples. Whenever you are asking questions about regexp, you should give sufficient examples to make it clear what you want to accept and what you want to reject.

Comment: @심형보 Updated my answer